# Extract values based on conidtion of another column

Tags: r

```
case_number <- c("1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3") 
type <- c("STD", "STD2", "STD", "STD3", "STD2", "STD", "STD2") 
date <- as.Date(c('2008-11-1','2009-3-25','2010-3-14',"2010-10-14","2010-11-14", '2015-3-14', '2015-4-15')) 

data <- data.frame(case_number,type, date)
```

I was wondering how would I extract the unique `case_number` that contains `STD` and `STD2` next to each other sorted by date?

In this case it would be 1 and 3 since for 2, `STD3` occurs in between `STD1` and `STD2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming every `case_number` would have both the values , another option is to check the position of `"STD"` and `"STD2"` and select groups where the difference is equal to 1.

```
check_fun <- function(x) {
   abs(diff(c(which.max(x == "STD"), which.max(x == "STD2")))) == 1
}

library(dplyr)

data %>% group_by(case_number) %>% filter(check_fun(type))

# case_number type  date      
#  <fct>       <fct> <date>    
#1 1           STD   2008-11-01
#2 1           STD2  2009-03-25
#3 3           STD   2015-03-14
#4 3           STD2  2015-04-15
```

Or if you just need the unique `case_number`

```
data %>% 
  group_by(case_number) %>% 
  filter(check_fun(type)) %>% 
  pull(case_number) %>% 
  unique

#[1] 1 3
#Levels: 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a shot:

```r
myfilter <- function(x) {
  r <- rle(x %in% c("STD", "STD2"))
  any(r$lengths[r$values] > 1)
}

library(dplyr)
data %>%
  group_by(case_number) %>%
  filter(myfilter(type)) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 4 x 3
#   case_number type  date      
#   <fct>       <fct> <date>    
# 1 1           STD   2008-11-01
# 2 1           STD2  2009-03-25
# 3 3           STD   2015-03-14
# 4 3           STD2  2015-04-15
```

It does not care about order, just about finding either of them in a chain of two (or more).

Comment: (Assuming the data has no repetitions e.g. a group with `c('STD', 'STD')` as part of the `type` column)